# Show text in a box when hovering over word

Tags: html, r, r-markdown

I would like to show a definition of a word in a R markdown file when hovering over a word.

For a link it can be done like this: `[I'm an inline-style link with title](https://www.google.com "Google's Homepage")` Upon hovering over `I'm an inline-style link with title` the text `Google's Homepage` will pop up. However, I would like to do the same for a word and give the definition of the word in a box without the link.

Something like: `[word]("Definition of word that pops up in a box upon hovering")`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option is the [`tippy`](https://github.com/JohnCoene/tippy) package.

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(tippy)
```

This is a 
```{r echo = FALSE}
tippy("word.", tooltip = "Definition of word that pops up in a box upon hovering")
```
I would like to know its definition.
````

[image]

Comment: love this simple package that adds a whole new dynamic to Rmarkdown text. Thank you

Comment: This is really interesting. Is there a way to do this inline (without R code?)

Comment: How could I use Latex input to pass into the tooltip, to get math formulas inside the hovering box?

Answer (score 6):

Found [a solution](https://forum.obsidian.md/t/inner-tooltip-or-popup-popover-as-markdown/12381/2) here.

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

# Introduction to tooltip or popups

This is a <abbr title="Definition of word that pops up in a box upon hovering">word.</abbr> I would like to know its definition.
````

Would be nice to be able to change the tooltip.

[This webpage](https://www.samanthaming.com/tidbits/98-html-abbr/) can help you customize the tag (Abbreviate Your Code with HTML abbr Tag).

I'm also looking of a way to have a [Wikipedia hover box style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Abbr/doc).

Again, you can avoid the 'default' box when you hover the text and change it as you like: this website provides examples to modify your 'tooltip' box.