# How can I add a tooltip to an inline word in RMarkdown?

Tags: html, r, r-markdown

I want to use the package `tippy` to add a tooltip over a **in-line** word on my RMarkdown document. However, the solution provided on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65706219/show-text-in-a-box-when-hovering-over-word/65707300#65707300) breaks the desired word into a new paragraph:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(tippy)
```

This is a 
```{r echo = FALSE}
tippy("word.", tooltip = "Definition of word that pops up in a box upon hovering")
```
I would like to know its definition.

This is a `r tippy("word.", tooltip = "Definition of word that pops up in a box upon hovering")`
I would like to know its definition.
````

[The result looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBUjJ.png). Both the chunk and in-line code solutions do not work. The package documentation implies that the in-line solution should work. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Works fine for me within the RStudio viewer as well as Firefox. Try updating all relevant packages  (rmarkdown, knitr, htmltools, .... )

Comment: Good to know is a local issue. I've updated all packages and ran the code from different folders, still getting the same issue though. Will try reinstalling RStudio, pandoc and R. Thanks!

Comment: What does your YAML look like? You didn't specify what output file you are rendering to, that could be part of the problem, pandoc will help if you want PDF, but will have no effect if you want to render to HTML.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to use tippy in "inline-mode" in one of my pkgdown articles. See the first two paragraphs [here](https://statistikat.github.io/STATcubeR/dev/articles/od_table.html). Basically, you need to wrap your word into an inline container (in my case `<u>`) and give it an id. Then, use a separate chunk to reference the element by id and add a tooltip.

````
---
output: html_document
---

This is a <u id='word'>word</u> in a sentence

```{r, echo=FALSE}
tippy::tippy_this(elementId = "word", tooltip = "tooltip")
```
````

You'll need to make sure that the return value of `tippy::tippy_this()` is printed in the rmarkdown document. This means that `tippy::tippy_this()` needs to appear at the end of the code chunk and the chunk is set to `results="markup"`, which is the default.

I'd be very interested in hearing if there is an easier solution to this but for the meantime, I'll be happy using this approach.

Answer (score 0):

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Daniel"
date: "4/6/2021"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(tippy)
```

This is a 
```{r echo = FALSE, results='asis'}
tippy("word.", tooltip = "Definition of word that pops up in a box upon hovering")
```
````

Notice the *results='asis'* which gave me your desired output, this is an HTML output file viewed in Firefox with my mouse.

[image]