# How to highlight inline code output in R Markdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, higher

I have an inline code within the R markdown document (e.g. `sum(1:10)`) that gives a specific output (here `55`).

I aim to get the result (`55`), but have it highlighted so that when one hovers over it or clicks it, the underlying code would display.

Is this possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66950132/how-can-i-add-a-tooltip-to-an-inline-word-in-rmarkdown?